# Trying to use schtasks to run bubbaA.bat at 10:00 a.m each day using the following

Tags: windows-xp, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

```
schtasks /c1reate /tn "bubbaA.bat" /tr "\"\d:\1\sapd\tastks\" arguments" /sc daily /sd 07/22/2010 /st 10:00:00 /Ru system /RP *
```

INFO: The Schedule Task "bubbaA.bat" will be created under user name ("NT AUTHOR
ITY\SYSTEM").
WARNING: Password will be ignored for "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" user.
ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

1. You've got a "1" in the word "create"
2. the /tr argument has multiple double-quotes and doesn't contain the name of the 'program' to run.
3. You don't need a "/sd" if you wan it to start today.
4. If you run as system, it can't run the program from a network location (I'm wildly assuming that's what your trying to do with the double backslash in the "tr" argument, though it's an invalid network location too). If you run as Network Service you can do that, but the computer account needs permission to access the network location.
5. You can't set the password for a system account, just leave that part off.